# students with the highest 3 marks

Tags: expressions

Every student has a mark and I want to refer to the students with the highest mark, with the second highest mark, and with the third highest mark. Can I simply say "the students with the highest 3 marks"? Or should I say "the top 3 students in mark"?

Answer (score 2):

"the students with the highest 3 marks" is quite understandable, but I might re-arrange slightly:

> the students with the three highest marks.
>
> The three top students
>
> The three students with the highest marks

Are also possible, and in context mean the same.